# Repositioning of label

Tags: android, ios, positioning, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'd like to ask you, how to use "center" property of a view (for example label). If I set it, nothing happens, the respective label sets itself to the center of screen no matter what I set as point x and y.:20 in creation, but I need to center it later.

**My code**

```
var width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
var height = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight; //create simple window 
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        width:width,
        height:height,
        backgroundColor:"#ffffff"
}); 
//add button to window with predefined left padding 
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({ 
        title:"Press me", 
        left:20, 
        color:"#000000" 
});
window.add(button);
button.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    //this should set button position to center, but does nothing  
    button.setCenter(width/2, height/2);
});
window.open();
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with your code? thanks

Comment: var width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth; 
var height = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight; 
//create simple window 
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({ 
width:width, 
height:height, 
backgroundColor:"#ffffff" 
}); 
//add button to window with predefined left padding 
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({ 
title:"Press me", 
left:20, 
color:"#000000" 
}); 
window.add(button); 
button.addEventListener("click", function() 
{ 
//this should set button position to center, but does nothing 
button.setCenter(width/2, height/2); 
}); 
window.open();

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing without code to look at, but what is probably happening is you label is set to `width:Ti.UI.SIZE` so the centering looks like nothing changed because the label is the same size as the text, what you probably want to do is set `width:Ti.UI.FILL` or some other width bigger than you text and then your label will center because the width of the label will be larger than the text.

Comment: Just a tip that builds on Mike's answer:  sometimes it can be informative to set a border or a background color on the element in question so that you can easily see how big it is.